# I am unable to find the Principled Volume Shader within my Cycle nodes. Any idea why?

Tags: node-editor

I am unable to find the Principled Volume Shader within my Cycle nodes. Any idea why?

Unable to find within my list. I do have the Principled BSDF but not principled Volume

I am running 2.79 on a mac.

Comment: The principled volume shader will be available in 2.8. To try it on an earlier version you can Download 2.79 from the **experimental builds** at https://builder.blender.org/download/.

Comment: Thank you. I had noticed on my PC at home I had it available. Thank you for your response.